# How do I start using make in git bash

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

Straight up new to the whole thing, i need to start using make and I dont know where to type my

```
make program: main.o funcs.o
    g++ main.o funcs.o -o program

make main.o: main.cpp funcs.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

make funcs.o: funcs.cpp funcs.h
    g++ -c funcs.cpp
```

How do i create the "makefile" file in my directory, does it have a file extension? Once i create it do i just start typing these in the terminal or do i edit my makefile, is it like a makefile.txt and i edit that to add rules?

Comment: I am assuming that you are using windows.
You can treat `Makefile` as any other file in the directory. Use your favorite editor to create a file named `Makefile` (no extension like `.txt`). You can edit the file using any editor of your choice; even notepad for that matter. You would find many tutorials and [beginner's guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=writing+your+first+makefile) online for writing makefiles.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally doable in Git Bash as it is a mingw environment which can run any executable compiled for that - not just git itself.

Here are other tools that can be run - including make:
[How to add more to Git Bash on Windows](https://gist.github.com/evanwill/0207876c3243bbb6863e65ec5dc3f058)

credits to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66525071/12438919

Answer (score 0):

Git Bash contains necessary tools (like core utilities, wget, cURL etc.) for you to use it as a version control environment. It is a stripped down version of MSYS2 and there's no way to extend it.

If you want to do full-fledged development in such an environment, you should look into using MSYS2 as your environment, where you can add packages using `pacman` command (the same as in Arch Linux / Manjaro). There are build tools like `make` and GCC, as well as Python and Perl. It's a complete version of development environment (including Git).

https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: so is there no way for me to use make in git bash then?

Comment: @fatlady98 Unfortunately, no. You can't use Git Bash for anything beyond basic tasks and Git.

Comment: This isn't true. All you need is the correct `PATH` environment variable pointing to the correct paths for your development tools.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `git bash`, you might consider, if you are with Windows 10, using [WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).

See for instance [Using C++ and WSL in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl), where, after a `sudo apt-get install build-essential gdb`, you would get everything you need (`make`, `g++`, ...)