# How to run "make" command in gitbash in windows?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, git-bash

Can anyone help me to run Makefile in windows using "make" command. When I try to run from git bash, am getting following error,

$ make build
bash: make: command not found

$ make deploy
bash: make: command not found

Is there anyway to install this in gitbash or something or is there any other windows tool I need to use?

Comment: Did you try to specify the path to _make_ explicitly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like Make isn't in your git-bash's path.

A quick search shows [this guide](https://gist.github.com/evanwill/0207876c3243bbb6863e65ec5dc3f058), which suggests the following steps:

- Go to ezwinports.
- Download make-4.1-2-without-guile-w32-bin.zip (get the version without guile).
- Extract zip.
- Copy the contents to your Git\mingw64\ merging the folders, but do NOT overwrite/replace any existing files.

The guide is several years old. It may behoove you to read some of the comments before taking action.

Comment: it perfectly works, as of november 2022 its with make-4.4
thanks so much

Answer (score 25):

You can also use chocolatey to install it:

```
choco install make
```

Here's the [package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/make).